# Javascript dot navigation not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am quite new to coding and I am trying to implement a dot navigation bar. Below is my code.

```html
<html>
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <style>
/* Init */
html { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
body { 
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: #EA7E00; 
}
.dot-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
/* Fin Init */

.dot-nav--item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 16px; height: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  &:before, &:after { content: ""; }
  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px; bottom: -1px; left: -1px; right: -1px;
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all .3s;
  }
  &:after {
    display: block;
    width: 3px; height: 30px;
    margin: 13px auto 0;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  &:last-child:after { display:none; }
  &:hover { cursor: pointer; }
  &.is-active:before {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
.dot-nav--link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate(-120%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 10px; 
  opacity: 0;
  color: #111; background-color: #fff;
  transition: all .3s;
  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 100%; 
    width: 0; height: 0;
    border-width: 6px 0 6px 8px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
    border-style: solid;    
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  
  .dot-nav--item:hover & {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-110%, -50%);
  }
}
      </style>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.dot-nav--item').on('click', function(){
  $this = $(this),
  $siblings = $this.siblings();
  
  $this.addClass('is-active');
  $siblings.removeClass('is-active');
})
      </script>
  </head>
  <body><nav class="dot-nav">
  <ul class="dot-nav--list list-unstyled">
    <li class="dot-nav--item is-active"><a href="#" class="dot-nav--link">Lorem ipsum dolor.</a></li>
    <li class="dot-nav--item"><a href="#" class="dot-nav--link">Assumenda, officia omnis.</a></li>
    <li class="dot-nav--item"><a href="#" class="dot-nav--link">Sed, alias totam.</a></li>
    <li class="dot-nav--item"><a href="#" class="dot-nav--link">Officia, itaque, vitae!</a></li>
    <li class="dot-nav--item"><a href="#" class="dot-nav--link">Repellendus, veritatis, deserunt.</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
  </body>
    </html>
```

The dots do not seem to be showing content when I hover over it and does not fill when I click on it either. I can't seem to find what is wrong. I suspect it has something to do with the script source but I am not so sure. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This is not how to import external `CSS`: `<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>`. You need to use `<link>` with your external `CSS`. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)

Comment: The way you construct HTML is wrong.

Comment: @LwinHtooKo I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I am quite new to coding as well, in what way is the construction wrong?

Comment: @AndyHoffman Hi, after changing it, it still doesn't seem to be working!

Comment: Your CSS isn't actually CSS, it is LESS or SASS or something like that - yet I don't see you embedding an according script to process this (which browsers don't do on their own yet), so you can't actually expect that to work. _"I forgot to mention that I am quite new to coding as well"_ - SO is not a place to teach you the basics, or a replacement for proper research and tutorials.

Comment: are expecting like this? https://jsfiddle.net/z7ftksad/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Hi, yes, I am expecting something like this!

Answer (score 0):

You have added the visible styles in a wrong place. Look at the following syntax

```
 .dot-nav--item:hover & {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
   transform: translate(-110%, -50%);
 }
```

The above style you have added under the class `.dot-nav--link`. This is wrong. It should be like below and you have to place after the `.dot-nav--links` declarations.

```
.dot-nav--item:hover .dot-nav--link {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
   transform: translate(-110%, -50%);
}
```

So whenever you hover the items it will try to find the child with the class `.dot-nav--link` and make it visible. Not sure what you are trying to achieve through jquery code.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/z7ftksad/1/)

Comment: Hi, I have tried this and it is still not working properly

Comment: Hi, it's fine, I've solved it by adding in the missing required source files!